# How to handle a large text file in javascript need a slicing algorithm

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my head around splicing a file, and whilst I can read certain parts of the file as per the tutorial [here.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files)

I can't work out how to write a loop, so that I read the entire file in chunks.

Needless to say I feel I'm well off the mark but here's the code I've been working on.

```
var loops = file.size / 10;
var start = 0;
var stop = file.size / 10;

for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
  var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
  reader.readAsText(blob);
  start = stop;
  stop += stop;
}
```

I'm trying to read the file in chunks 1 10th of its total size. By starting with the bytes range 0 - 1/10th of the size, then moving up to have my start byte at the position of the end byte and doubling the end byte, but I realise this isn't the correct way to be doing this,

I've got hold of the file:

```
File {webkitRelativePath: "", lastModifiedDate: Thu Nov 07 2013 07:56:00 GMT+0000 (GMT), name: "TestData.txt", type: "text/plain", size: 136000000…}
```

but this code gives me an error about my reader not being usable at this time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to calculate the length of the chunks and add that length to stop at the end of every loop.

```
var loops = 10;
var chunkLength = file.size / loops;
var start = 0;
var stop = chunkLength;

for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
  var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
  reader.readAsText(blob);
  start = stop;
  stop += chunkLength;
}
```

Comment: Theres still the issue that when the `start`is assigned the `stop`its a byte thats already been read. Is there not a way to ensure each chunk is unique.

Comment: a wild guess - remove the `+ 1` part from `stop + 1`?